# create thread - passing arguments

Tags: c, multithreading, function, parameter-passing

I am attempting on creating multiple threads that each thread calculates a prime. I am trying to pass a second argument to a function using thread create. It keeps throwing up errors.

```
void* compute_prime (void* arg, void* arg2)
{
```

here is my main() with the create thread. &primeArray[i] after &max_prime is giving me the errors.

```
 for(i=0; i< num_threads; i++)
 {
    primeArray[i]=0;
    printf("creating threads: \n");
    pthread_create(&primes[i],NULL, compute_prime, &max_prime, &primeArray[i]);
    thread_number = i;
    //pthread_create(&primes[i],NULL, compPrime, &max_prime);
 }

 /* join threads */
 for(i=0; i< num_threads; i++)
{
    pthread_join(primes[i], NULL);
    //pthread_join(primes[i], (void*) &prime);
    //pthread_join(primes[i],NULL);
    //printf("\nThread %d produced: %d primes\n",i, prime);
    printf("\nThread %d produced: %d primes\n",i, primeArray[i]);
    sleep(1);
}
```

the error i get is:

```
myprime.c: In function âmainâ:
myprime.c:123: warning: passing argument 3 of âpthread_createâ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/pthread.h:227: note: expected âvoid * (*)(void *)â but argument is of type âvoid * (*)(void *, void *)â
myprime.c:123: error: too many arguments to function âpthread_createâ
```

It works fine if i take out the second argument.

Comment: see answer below, also check out [link](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#References) for a good pthread reference site.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can only pass a single argument to the function that you are calling in the new thread. Create a struct to hold both of the values and send the address of the struct.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    //Or whatever information that you need
    int *max_prime;
    int *ith_prime;
} compute_prime_struct;

void *compute_prime (void *args) {
    compute_prime_struct *actual_args = args;
    //...
    free(actual_args);
    return 0;
}
#define num_threads 10
int main() {
    int max_prime = 0;
    int primeArray[num_threads];
    pthread_t primes[num_threads];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        compute_prime_struct *args = malloc(sizeof *args);
        args->max_prime = &max_prime;
        args->ith_prime = &primeArray[i];
        if(pthread_create(&primes[i], NULL, compute_prime, args)) {
            free(args);
            //goto error_handler;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of std::thread, the user can pass arguments to the thread function in the following method

std::thread(funcName,arg1,arg2);

for instance,

```
//for a thread function, 
void threadFunction(int x,int y){
   std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
}

// u can pass x and y values as below
std::thread mTimerThread;
mTimerThread = std::thread(threadFunction,1,12);
```

Comment: Wrong language, C, not C++

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of [Manakarse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13132001/10388412) , everything is really good but you need a

**pthread_join(thread[i],NULL)**

just to be sure all of threads will successfully execute before end of main thread("main will "waiting" while all of threads aren't finished yet)
;

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int stop_flag;
    char name[30];
} _process_data;

typedef struct 
{
    int meter_no;
    int port_no;
} _process_control;

typedef struct 
{
   _process_data *process_data;
   _process_control *process_control;
} compute_prime_struct;

void *compute_prime (void *args) 
{
    compute_prime_struct *actual_args = args;
      printf("actual_args->process_data->stop_flag [%d]\n",actual_args->process_data->stop_flag);
      printf("actual_args->process_data->name [%s]\n",actual_args->process_data->name);
      printf("actual_args->process_control->meter_no [%d]\n",actual_args->process_control->meter_no);
      printf("actual_args->process_control->port_no [%d]\n",actual_args->process_control->port_no);
    free(actual_args);
    return 0;
}
void fill_data(_process_data *process_data,_process_control *process_control)
{
    process_data->stop_flag=1;
    process_data->name[0]='P';
    process_control->meter_no=6;
    process_control->port_no=22;
    
    pthread_t tid;
    
    compute_prime_struct *args = malloc(sizeof (*args));
    args->process_data = malloc(sizeof (*args->process_data));
    args->process_control = malloc(sizeof (*args->process_control));

    memcpy (args->process_data, process_data, sizeof (args->process_data));
    memcpy (args->process_control, process_control, sizeof (*args->process_control));
        
        if(pthread_create(&tid, NULL, compute_prime, args)) 
        {
            free(args);
            printf("Error here");
        }
        sleep(1);
}

int main() 
{
     _process_data process_data;
     _process_control process_control;
     
     fill_data(&process_data,&process_control);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.