# Save threads output in variable

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I have simple client/server app. And i am using threads. 
This is example of my thread.

```
void * thread2()

    {   
        val1 = 6*a*a;
        val2 = a*a*a;

            printf("va1 = %f \n", va1);
            printf("val2 = %f \n", val2);
    }
```

And this is how i am calling it in server

```
// LEVEL 3
    if(level == 3){
    int status;
    pthread_t tid1,tid2,tid3,tid4;


    pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid3,NULL,thread3,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid3,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid4,NULL,thread4,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid4,NULL);

    level = 4;
}
```

Problem is that everything is printed in server instead of chat and i dont know how to use it in `send()` function

This is example of my `send()` function

```
s = send(newSocket, msg2, sizeof(msg2), 0);
```

Like how can i save output from threads in variable or something. I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an argument to the thread you're calling. If you need to pass several arguments, use one struct that contains all of them. If you pass by reference you can then afterwards get the result back after the thread completed.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131982/create-thread-passing-arguments/53859186) post, first answer.

In the struct you're passing you should include a bool **executed**, that way you can check in your main function if the thread has fully executed yet or not, so you don't extract a value that has nog been set yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you actually want to save the output of the thread, printing it on "chat" and not in "server" as you said. Try simply modifying the `stdout` to be that chat you are talking about. Check redirection with `dup` family.